# Why does my Castle settlement show insufficient power?

Tags: fallout-4

My settlement at the Castle has 32 power for three people and it's still showing up as red. What gives? Is there some hidden object that I need to power in order to satisfy the Workshop? Because I found the one existing pylon in the courtyard and connecting it didn't solve it. Or is this a bug?

Comment: Did  you complete [Old Guns](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Old_Guns) yet? Maybe there's a bulb in there?

Comment: Im not positive, but I think "bigger" settlements require higher numbers, bigger meaning population and perhaps land mass, or just ones considered "advanced" like the Castle. When you view settlements in the Pip Boy (Workshops tab of the Data menu), I have a happy settlement of 8 at the drive in with power = 3, but power is flagged (but not red) at the Castle, population 11, and they have 45 power. Wtf right?

Comment: As mentioned though, the number of unpowered stuff around the settlement definitely has an effect.

Comment: @Dpeif I don't think the number of settlers has any effect on the amount of power required. I have settlements with 10+ people with just 3 power for the recruitment beacon, and no warning, and settlements with no people that require power due to the presence of a water purifier.

Comment: @DCShannon that's a good point, agreed

Comment: This was driving me crazy too, but then last night I noticed my power now shows as green. In the meantime I'm fairly sure I didn't make any relevant changes: no new generators, rewiring, etc. I might have added a settler or some plants, but that seems unrelated. I'm curious to see whether time fixes your problem too.

Comment: There are lights and connectors in the armory area of the castle that aren't connected to the rest of the grid. These are only accessible after a particular quest (old guns maybe).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a bunch of lightbulbs and an industrial water purifier that need power.

You can see the purifier out of one of the windows. There is a pylon with a switch on it in the courtyard you can connect to to hook up all the light bulbs and the purifier. It was not obvious to me until I traced the wires from the lights.

Since there's a switch on the pylon, you might need to make sure that it is actually switched on.

Comment: The lightbulbs and purifier all appear to be pre-connected to the pylon I mentioned in the courtyard. Everything lights up at night. I imagine that's everything...

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone still has problems with the lights at the castle, it is right in our faces. I feel stupid after realizing what needed to be done. By the workbench there should be a power switch. You need to hook up a generator into **that** switch. I was also focused on the big thing in the middle and didn't pay attention.

Comment: That's the connector I was referring to in my answer. Do you think this is something other than what @Sean was referring to?

Answer (score 2):

I had this happen after my castle had been working fine for ages. All my generators were still hooked up and reported generating electricity, but the items I had powered all were red, including ones that didn't go through the central switch.

I ended up having to remove a copper wire from each generator and replace it, then everything started working again.

Answer (score -1):

You need 13 power attached to the switched pylon to run the lights and purifier. 
Or you can scrap that huge purifier. I had a separate water source already so that's how I finally satisfied the castle's power requirements.

Answer (score -4):

I just figured it out...it's definitely the purifier in the back of tower....and power to pylon to the right of the work bench. And make sure you power the central radio brodcaster.

Comment: Both of the previous answers already say this.